# Missing data from HTTP response

Tags: java, android, api, http

I've been trying to use the [Forecast.io API](https://developer.forecast.io/) and the JAR that was provided by their website for my application. But when making web API calls it looks like the data that is being returned by the site isn't fully downloaded.

I try it print the data and it appears that it is not all the information.

I'm using this code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI website = new URI(requestURL);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(website);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
scanner = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
    .getContent()));

String availalbe;
while ((availalbe = scanner.readLine()) != null) {
   res += availalbe;
}
```

Data that is printed out (it stops partway through what is expected):

> {"latitude":51.7589177,"longitude":-0.2342903,"timezone":"Europe/London","offset":1,"currently":{"time":1370612854,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0,"temperature":20.65,"dewPoint":10.56,"windSpeed":9.92,"windBearing":59,"cloudCover":0.34,"humidity":0.5,"pressure":1023.91,"visibility":10.75,"ozone":356.06},"minutely":{"summary":"Light rain in 30 min.","icon":"rain","data":[{"time":1370612820,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370612880,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370612940,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613000,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613060,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613120,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613180,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613240,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613300,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613360,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613420,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613480,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613540,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613600,"precipIntensity":0},{"time":1370613660,"precipIntensity":0.107,"precipIntensityError":0.055,"precipProbability":0.01,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370613720,"precipIntensity":0.111,"precipIntensityError":0.057,"precipProbability":0.01,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370613780,"precipIntensity":0.132,"precipIntensityError":0.065,"precipProbability":0.01,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370613840,"precipIntensity":0.137,"precipIntensityError":0.062,"precipProbability":0.03,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370613900,"precipIntensity":0.142,"precipIntensityError":0.065,"precipProbability":0.03,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370613960,"precipIntensity":0.161,"precipIntensityError":0.072,"precipProbability":0.04,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614020,"precipIntensity":0.174,"precipIntensityError":0.074,"precipProbability":0.04,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614080,"precipIntensity":0.187,"precipIntensityError":0.077,"precipProbability":0.08,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614140,"precipIntensity":0.207,"precipIntensityError":0.084,"precipProbability":0.09,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614200,"precipIntensity":0.223,"precipIntensityError":0.088,"precipProbability":0.1,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614260,"precipIntensity":0.224,"precipIntensityError":0.094,"precipProbability":0.15,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614320,"precipIntensity":0.243,"precipIntensityError":0.102,"precipProbability":0.16,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614380,"precipIntensity":0.259,"precipIntensityError":0.108,"precipProbability":0.17,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614440,"precipIntensity":0.262,"precipIntensityError":0.108,"precipProbability":0.24,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614500,"precipIntensity":0.28,"precipIntensityError":0.115,"precipProbability":0.25,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614560,"precipIntensity":0.3,"precipIntensityError":0.12,"precipProbability":0.25,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614620,"precipIntensity":0.322,"precipIntensityError":0.125,"precipProbability":0.26,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614680,"precipIntensity":0.33,"precipIntensityError":0.125,"precipProbability":0.33,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614740,"precipIntensity":0.352,"precipIntensityError":0.131,"precipProbability":0.34,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614800,"precipIntensity":0.375,"precipIntensityError":0.136,"precipProbability":0.34,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614860,"precipIntensity":0.38,"precipIntensityError":0.14,"precipProbability":0.42,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614920,"precipIntensity":0.402,"precipIntensityError":0.147,"precipProbability":0.42,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370614980,"precipIntensity":0.425,"precipIntensityError":0.154,"precipProbability":0.42,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370615040,"precipIntensity":0.432,"precipIntensityError":0.157,"precipProbability":0.5,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370615100,"precipIntensity":0.454,"precipIntensityError":0.164,"precipProbability":0.5,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370615160,"precipIntensity":0.477,"precipIntensityError":0.168,"precipProbability":0.5,"precipType":"rain"},{"time":1370615220,"precipIntensit

Method calling the Forecast Api test class

```
    public void weatherLike()
{
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.getLocation(MyService.this, new LocationResult() {
        ForecastIO fio = null;
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                try {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                fio= new ForecastIO("[API_KEY]");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                speakOut(user + ", I am not able to locate you");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally
            {

                System.out.println("Latitude: "+fio.getLatitude());
                System.out.println("Longitude: "+fio.getLongitude());
                System.out.println("Timezone: "+fio.getTimezone());
                System.out.println("Offset: "+fio.offsetValue());
                System.out.println("\n");

            }
            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Check HTTP content with Wireshark

Comment: Why use a `BufferedReader`? Just use an `InputStream` and swallow the whole; print the output in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and use `.toString()` at the end

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: @fge i got more information but still not all

Comment: You only need to manually consume the response stream if your are using `HttpURLConnection`, or if you have some kind of multipart response. Simplify your life by utilizing the [`EntityUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) class that comes with Apache HttpComponents (`String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`). Simple right? Don't forget to verify your response status before proceeding down the 'happy path'.

Comment: @Perception still the same problem. it isn't anything with the connection??

Comment: @MoAdel - not likely. Could be your server side is sending incomplete data (doubtful). Or your sysout is getting truncated. Might be helpful if you included the URL you are calling (with API key removed).

Comment: @Perception https://api.forecast.io/forecast/[API_KEY]/51.7588645,-0.2343055?units=auto

Comment: @MoAdel - I have no problem accessing the URL you're using. Here is a [Gist that illustrates the call](https://gist.github.com/sevenhillsoftware/5730439).

Comment: @Perception still tried it and same problem.so it is either something to do with StrictMode.enabledefaults() or the Location method that include a call to the ApiTest

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no..i updated the question and added the Location abstract method of the location Interface. which inside it i create a Forecast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the Answers. i found out that My LogCat was trucating long messages no wonder why i never showed a full reply.

in case any one fell in the same problem. 
Split the String reply to pieces using this code

```
if (sb.length() > 4000) {
            Log.v("length", "sb.length = " + sb.length());
            int chunkCount = sb.length() / 4000;     // integer division
            for (int i = 0; i <= chunkCount; i++) {
                int max = 4000 * (i + 1);
                if (max >= sb.length()) {
                    Log.v("1st", "chunk " + i + " of " + chunkCount + ":" + sb.substring(4000 * i));
                } else {
                    Log.v("2nd", "chunk " + i + " of " + chunkCount + ":" + sb.substring(4000 * i, max));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader use 'buffer' so U have to use 'flush method' (or close method )
refer link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        public static String getResponseText(String stringUrl) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println("webservice 1");
    URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
    HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        System.out.println("webservice 2");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
        String strLine = null;
        while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(strLine);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```